# Invert dict of sets in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the most Pythonic way to take a dict of lists and produce a new `dict` with the list items as keys and the previous `dict`'s keys as list items.

Here's a visual explanation:

```
favorite_fruits = {"alice": {"apple", "orange"}, "bob": {"apple"}, "carol": {"orange"}}
people_by_fruit = {"orange": {"carol", "alice"}, "apple": {"bob", "alice"}}
```

Here's the best I have at the moment:

```
from collections import defaultdict
favorite_fruits = {"alice": {"apple", "orange"}, "bob": {"apple"}, "carol": {"orange"}}
people_by_fruit = defaultdict(set)
for person, fruit in favorite_fruits.items():
    for fruit in fruit:
        people_by_fruit[fruit].add(person)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-inverse-a-mapping

Comment: @kushj: that solves a slightly different problem

Comment: @TreyHunner you did it in your code, this code looks fine. Please, post your specific concerns as I don't see any issues with this.

Comment: You can write it in just one line by use dict compression and `map()`. But IMHO that is not really better and even a trick because in Python 3 map is a generator and executed just when you evaluate generator I.e. you should add something like `[:]` at the end of `map` code.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico: that's an interesting idea but I'm having trouble envisioning that.

Comment: I assume you aren't bothered by the fact that the result is a `defaultdict` rather than a `dict`?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I do believe you are quite good as you are. The simple inversion listed in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-inverse-a-mapping) (from comments) does *not* work when you want to split up the set values of your first dict. You could try something like a dict comprehension with a double for loop, but that doesn't work either as the second time you get a fruit it will overwrite the first one.

The only thing I would like to change in your answer is to use the plural of fruit, `fruits`, so that you don't do the `for fruit in fruit` which looks kind of hairy, and has the potential for code breaking as you're overwriting a variable with the same variable. Not good. In other words:

```
people_by_fruit = defaultdict(set)
for person, fruits in favorite_fruits.items():
    for fruit in fruits:
        people_by_fruit[fruit].add(person)
```

Comment: Nice catch on the repeat variable name. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

First of all my opinion is that your version is quite close to the best one. But it is possible to use a single `for` cycle or write it in just one line by use of `map()` and list compression instead of nested `for` cycles:

```
from collections import defaultdict

direct = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [3], "c": [2, 4, 5], "d": [6]}


def invert(d):
    ret = defaultdict(set)
    for key, values in d.items():
        for value in values:
            ret[value].add(key)
    return ret


def invert_alt(d):
    ret = defaultdict(set)
    list(map(lambda h: ret[h[1]].add(h[0]), [(key, value) for key in d for value in d[key]]))
    return ret


def invert_final(d):
    ret = defaultdict(set)
    for key, value in [(key, value) for key in d for value in d[key]]:
        ret[value].add(key)
    return ret


print(invert(direct))
print(invert_alt(direct))
print(invert_final(direct))
```

Is it clear that `invert_alt()` have too much issues to use it:

1. You should use `list()` trick just in Python3 because `map()` is a generator and not evaluated until the code *access* to generator element, you don't need it in Python2.
2. This implementation uses `map`'s side effect to do its job and my position is to avoid any use of side effects to complete the core jobs.
3. Is really hard to understand.

For `invert_final()` you pay a little bit in clearness to remove a nested indentation: maybe a good compromise. Due to Python's formatting if you remove nesting indentation that is always a good goal.

Comment: In `invert_final` you don't remove a nested cycle, you add a cycle and a list comprehension. In `invert_alt` you add a list generation to force execution of generator of an extra lamda/map expression.  Both versions going a little backwards, proving that the OP version  is actually a good version: Readable, memory efficient and effective.

Comment: Sorry,, I've used wrong term. I meant remove nestled indentation. Remove nested indentations are always a good point in Python. As I wrote `invert_alt` is wrong but I wrote it just because OP ask me in the comment. I've pointed that you pay little in readability but you remove indentation, nested indentation is a well know Python issue so remove one could be a valuable goal.

Comment: @holroy just for the records, Python developer put lot effort in list compression syntax and tools like `zip` `map` to make simple remove some nested indentations and make code more compact.. Try to write a five nested `for` cycle with a `if` logic inside ... You will love `zip` construct.

Comment: Readability and good line lengths are also good, if not better. Removing indentation on cost of clarity, is not a good trade off in my book.

Comment: I do love the different comprehensions available, not that keen on the not so recommended `map` though useful in some contexts. Choose the right tool for the right job. Nesting five `for` loops with `if` sounds like something in need of refactoring

Comment: @Micheled'Amico That last solution is interesting. I took the list comprehension and moved it into a generator expression on its own line (so the whole thing is equivalent to the original in time complexity): https://pastebin.com/eViMQ19n